# What's the best facebook python-sdk fork?

Tags: python, django, facebook

It looks like development has stalled on the official python-sdk.  There are 139 forks on github.  What's the most mature or best for using with Django.

EDIT:
By "official" I meant http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk.  I'm reluctant to use it because it has a number of pull requests that have been open for quite a while.

Comment: I built a [Chrome/Firefox extension](https://github.com/musically-ut/lovely-forks) to address this exact problem on Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [django-la-facebook](https://github.com/cartwheelweb/django-la-facebook). It was started to bridge the gap between all of the incomplete django facebook integration layers. It is also worked on by Jacob Burch of the ladjango meetup group fame, and Danny Greenfield of the django consultancy, [Cartwheel Web](http://www.cartwheelweb.com/) (no I don't work for them).

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/ this is the one facebook recommends... but if I were you I would just use graph API for python, since there is no complete solution